# Change a prop on a styled component and update appearance

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-proptypes

I'm very new to styled components (and I'm not great with React in general) and I can't quite get my head around them. I've created a basic example which is an abstraction of what I want to achieve. When I click on the box, I want the property `on` to be changed to `true` and for the colour of `<Box>` to be updated to green as per the `background-color` rule.

How do I achieve this? Especially in the instance where there could be an indeterminate number of boxes?

Component

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Box = styled.a`  
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: ${props => props.on ? 'green' : 'red' };
`;

Box.propTypes = {
    on: PropTypes.bool,
    onClick: PropTypes.func,
}

Box.defaultProps = {
    on: false,
    onClick: () => {},
}

export default Box;
```

Implementation

```
<Box on={ false } onClick={ }></Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would handle the state in its parent component. For example you could do something like this:

```
class Page extends Component {
  state = { on: false }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ on: !prevState.on }));
  }

  render() {
    return <Box on={this.state.on} onClick={this.handleClick} />
  }
}
```

Or even simpler using React hooks:

```
const Page = () => {
  const [on, setOn] = useState(false);
  return <Box on={on} onClick={() => setOn(on => !on)} />;
};
```

Here's an example of what you could do if you wanted 10 boxes

*(note: creating the onClick handler in the render method like I did could cause performance issues if you have a very large number of boxes)*

```
class Page extends Component {
  state = { boxes: Array(10).fill(false) }

  handleClick = (index) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      boxes: [
        ...prevState.boxes.slice(0, index),
        !prevState.boxes[index],
        ...prevState.boxes.slice(index)
      ]
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.state.boxes.map((on, index) =>
          <Box on={on} onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)} />
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sadly in my scenario I'm restricted to an earlier version of React that doesn't support hooks (apparently), so the first solution would be best. Is there a more succinct way of managing the states if there were 10 boxes?

Comment: @ChrisWickham I just updated my answer with an example of doing this with 10 boxes

Answer (score 0):

// App.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Test from "./Test";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    on: false
  };
  handleChange = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ on: !prevState.on }));
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Test on={this.state.on} onClick={this.handleChange}>
          Hey
        </Test>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

// Test.js

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Box = styled.a`
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: ${props => (props.on ? "green" : "red")};
`;

Box.propTypes = {
  on: PropTypes.bool,
  onClick: PropTypes.func
};

Box.defaultProps = {
  on: false,
  onClick: () => {}
};

export default Box;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there any way of succinctly controlling the state of a indeterminate number of boxes? Or would each box need its own state?

Comment: The way I see, you need state for each box, but you could always use map and no need to write component again and again. If you want to always change color to green and red then you could write onclick logic inside Box component or may be even make it default. Also please edit question to add this requirement so that answers are according to requirements.